# PC hard-resets quite often in Ubuntu (but not in windows)

Tags: linux-kernel, crash

PC hard-resets quite often in Ubuntu.
**But not in windows never**.

It just resets during use with nothing in common.
It even resets during Ubuntu install.

These are the ones I've tried.

- IPDT Test : OK
- Memory Test : OK
- CPU Temperature : Not high
- Never overclocking or XMP
- Ubuntu 22.04 (Kernel 5.15)
- Ubuntu 20.04
- Ubuntu 18.04 (Kernel 5.4)
- Disable wayland
- Change SSD

I've tried for debugging:

- kdump : No dumped anything
- console with SerialPort : No output (No kernel crash)

The kernel doesn't crash, it just resets the PC.
**How can I debug it?**
There are no logs on the motherboard because not the server board.

Spec:

- MB : Asus Z390-P
- CPU : i9-9900
- GPU : No gpu (Intel CPU)

Comment: 1. Update BIOS to the very last available version 2. Reset it settings 3. Try a distro with the latest possible kernel, e.g. Fedora 37 beta (it's safe to install and use). Speaking of memory test, please try this one: https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm

Comment: I have already updated and downgraded the bios. Also memtest86 was also successful.

Comment: 4. Try to disable as many built-in motherboard devices as possible (LTP/COM ports/WiFi/etc. etc. etc.)

Comment: If it still doesn't help 5. Try to disable CPU power saving features.

Comment: If it still doesn't help 6. Unplug all possible peripheral devices and leave only e.g. mouse and keyboard

Comment: Thank you for answer. Disabling the integrated graphics and connecting an external graphics solved the problem...

Comment: If it still doesn't help 7. Increase the amount of dedicated RAM for your iGPU

Comment: That's a bug worth reporting! Please do: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues

Please provide as much info as possible: motherboard, BIOS release, RAM size, CPU type and the steps that lead to a hard reboot